# OpenLiberty NameNotFoundException: java:/comp/env

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I have a web app running in Tomcat correctly that I want to run on the new OpenLiberty server, the app is starting correctly inside OpenLiberty but at the moment of the database connection initiation is throwing the following exception:

```
[Default Executor-thread-15] 2018-03-15 15:02:30 ERROR TomcatConnectionManager:41 - Loading jdbc/mysql/myaap failure
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:/comp/env
    at com.ibm.ws.jndi.url.contexts.javacolon.internal.JavaURLName.<init>(JavaURLName.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.jndi.url.contexts.javacolon.internal.JavaURLNameParser.parse(JavaURLNameParser.java:39)
    at com.ibm.ws.jndi.url.contexts.javacolon.internal.JavaURLNameParser.parse(JavaURLNameParser.java:60)
    at com.ibm.ws.jndi.url.contexts.javacolon.internal.JavaURLContext$NameUtil.<init>(JavaURLContext.java:474)
    at com.ibm.ws.jndi.url.contexts.javacolon.internal.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:321)
    at com.ibm.ws.jndi.url.contexts.javacolon.internal.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:370)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
```

The above exception is thrown during the lookup phase:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
```

Is there any way to make it work on OpenLiberty doing less changes possible?

Answer (score 4):

On OpenLiberty the equivalent lookup would look like this:

```
    Context initContext = new InitialContext();
    Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
```

The key is that you need to use `java:comp/...` instead of `java:/comp/...`

---

The reason why Tomcat is different than Liberty is because Tomcat is just a servlet container and Liberty conforms to the full Java EE specification.

According to section [EE.5.2.2 of the Java EE 7 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/java_ee-7-fr-spec/JavaEE_Platform_Spec.pdf):

> The application component’s naming environment is composed of four logical
>   namespaces, representing naming environments with different scopes. The four
>   namespaces are:
>
> - java:comp – Names in this namespace are per-component (for example, per enterprise
>     bean). Except for components in a web module, each component gets
>     its own java:comp namespace, not shared with any other component. Components
>     in a web module do not have their own private component namespace.
>     See note below.
> - java:module – Names in this namespace are shared by all components in a
>     module (for example, all enterprise beans in a single EJB module, or all components
>     in a web module).
> - java:app – Names in this namespace are shared by all components in all modules
>     in a single application, where “single application” means a single deployment
>     unit, such as a single ear file, a single module deployed standalone, etc.
>     For example, a war file and an EJB jar file in the same ear file would both have
>     access to resources in the java:app namespace.
> - java:global – Names in this namespace are shared by all applications deployed
>     in an application server instance. Note that an application server instance
>     may represent a single server, a cluster of servers, an administrative
>     domain containing many servers, or even more. The scope of an application
>     server instance is product-dependent, but it must be possible to deploy multiple
>     applications to a single application server instance.

Comment: I've changed to: `java:comp/` but still getting javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:comp/

Comment: I just tried `initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");` and that worked for me.  Also, do you have the `jndi-1.0` feature enabled in your server.xml?  (or some other feature that pulls in `jndi-1.0`)

Comment: also, looking up `java:comp/` will not work but `java:comp` will

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem going between WebSphere and Tomcat.   I'm developing and testing on a Tomcat server and using utilities I can't change that handle the DB connection to our DB2.  On WebSphere it uses a constant set to "jdbc/COMPDB2" to retrieve the DataSource when I configure Tomcat and my Web.xml file it resolves to "java:comp/env/jdbc/SFCCDB2"

My work around for on local work space it to add a listener to copy the resource to the level in the InitialContext.  I'm not very experienced with the server side of things but this is working so far using TomEE 7.0.81.

```
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/SFCCDB2");
        javax.naming.Context envCtx = (javax.naming.Context) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        try{
            /*
            Added this because after redeploying code to the server it would error 
            connecting to the DB with an SQLException Datasource is closed
             */
            DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/COMPDB2");
            ctx.destroySubcontext("jdbc");
        } catch (NamingException e){
            //Doesn't exist; safe to just add
        }
        ctx.createSubcontext("jdbc");
        ctx.bind("jdbc/COMPDB2", ds);
        ctx.close();
```